# PowerBI Report Server credentials won't cache

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi, sql-server-2016

I've installed the on premise version of powerBI report server against our enterprise SQL Server installation and all is running and works well however everytime I visit the site (Using Edge or IE) I am prompted to enter my windows credentials once to access the site and again to access a powerbi report. Everytime I check rembember my credentials but I still get prompted.

Anybody know why? Our SQL 2012 SSRS servers don't have this issue.

Comment: This is a few months old, but maybe relevant to you? https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Power-BI-Desktop-keeps-asking-to-login-when-publishing-report-to/td-p/115312

Comment: Thanks for the fast response but unfortunately this applies to the desktop app rather than an on premise server installation. I have scoured their community but couldn't find as response.